Solved // Intel RST high memory usage
I've been giong crazy over the past few days trying to fix what I think is a memory leak caused by an unecessary Intel RST driver..
With absolutely no program running my memory usage is always above 80% (and most of the time above 95%). Running Poolmon in the Windows Toolkit has helped me indentify that it comes from  a non paged driver, tag "ismc"

I understand that this comes from Intel Rapid Storage so I would like to uninstall it.
However I can't find it in device managers, and have absolutely no clue where it is located (I'm on windows 11).
Would really appreciate the community's help on this one

If you manage to uninstall it the most probable result is an unbootable system.

do you have an idea of how to fix the memory leak ?

Make sure you're running the latest version of the IntelRST driver and firmware. That's the only way to fix this, realistically. So, have you checked for and installed any and all available system firmware updates and drivers?

yes I updated everything, maybe if I try to use AHCI instead of RST that would fix it ?

okay switching to AHCI I now have idle RAM usage of 60%... it's not optimal but it's better

So you have Intel RST installed.  Is Windows installed in a RAID configuration. You should avoid any system configuration changes until you provide adequate information to diagnose the problem. There is no reason to have Intel RST drivers installed if Windows is installed in a RAID configuration. One way to remove it is to installed the drivers, then uninstall the drivers, which goes back to which driver version you have installed specifically. It's also possible to remove system driver files with a simple command.

do you have an idea of how to fix the memory leak ? a developer fixes a memory leak by ensuring that all allocated memory is properly deallocated as soon as its done being used. a "memory leak" is a distinct type of software defect that occurs under specific conditions, so its not just "my app uses lots of memory" or even that "memory use increases over time". both of those conditions can be caused by a program functioning properly with no memory deallocation defects. an end user has no option to fix a memory leak other than to get updated fixed software

Hi everyone, I've ended up doing a factory reset of my computer this morning, did a fresh install  of everything, it fixed it.

@NabilBennis can you edit your post or answer your own question

Please do not add solutions to your questions and/or “solved” in the title. There is a mechanism to to mark a question as solved, and that is to accept an answer. So first answer your question below and then, after 48 hours, accept your own (or any other) answer.
